# Развернуть два проекта на одном домене

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли разместить два Asp.Net Core проекта на одном домене? Есть проект основного сайта (site.ru) и есть проект админки в этом же солюшене, хотелось бы чтоб админка была доступна по этому же домену (site.ru/admin или site/admin). Это возможно? На хостинг проекты гружу через ftp (обычный хостинг). Там не виртуалка и нет IIS.

Comment: IIS может такое сделать, почитайте

Comment: Можете дать ссылку?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/13.2.php да даже вот этого должно хватить

Comment: Честно говоря по вашей ссылке нет ответа на мой вопрос((

Comment: На хостинг проекты гружу через ftp (обычный хостинг)

Comment: Там не виртуалка и нет IIS

Comment: тогда добавьте в вопрос описание платформы

Comment: Добавил описание в вопрос

Comment: Как понимаю вариантов нет, только совместить в один проект...

Comment: насколько мне известно на домене существует конфиг с алиасами, которые привязывают определённые части проекта, к определённым адресам в запросах со стороны браузера. Но это для меня тёмный лес )

Answer (score 2):

Можно разместить хоть десять проектов. Для этого надо понимать, как все работает.

Как правило, сайты (в том числе и на Asp.Net Core) размещают за прокси сервером (обычно это nginx или apache). Эти прокси сервера принимают HTTP запросы от пользователей и перенаправляют их на нужный ресурс/приложение.

Вот схема для вашего случая:

[image: схема]

Как видите, вы можете запустить сколько-угодно приложений, при условии, что настроите прокси сервер соответствующим образом.

Вот скелет конфига для nginx в вашем случае:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.ru;

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:50001;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:50000;
    }
}
```

И вот пример, как привязать Asp.Net Core приложение к определенном порту:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 50001);
            })
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}
```